# How to get list of users in a facebook custom interest list?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is it possible to get a list of users in a Facebook custom interest list using the Graph API?

For example, how do I get the members of this custom list?

https://www.facebook.com/lists/2363232331997

Answer (score 0):

No, afaik there is no way to access lists with the Graph API. They don´t get mentioned at all in the API reference.